# gorm returns empty query just shows the id

Tags: go

l have a problem with gorm when l query all books it returns nothing but the id even though the data exist

[
{
"ID": 0,
"CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"DeletedAt": null,
"id": 4,
"bookname": "",
"authorname": "",
"pagesnumber": 0,
"bookreview": "",
"bookimage": 0,
"bookProgress": 0,
"endDate": "",
"startDate": ""
},
{
"ID": 0,
"CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"DeletedAt": null,
"id": 14,
"bookname": "",
"authorname": "",
"pagesnumber": 0,
"bookreview": "",
"bookimage": 0,
"bookProgress": 0,
"endDate": "",
"startDate": ""
}
]

func main

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var db *gorm.DB = nil

var err error

func main() {
    dsn := "root:azoz2012@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/crud?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    db, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Book{})
    db.Debug()
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/api/books", AllBooks)
    r.GET("/api/book/:id", OneBook)
    // r.POST("/posts", Store)
    // r.PUT("/posts/update/:id", Update)
    // r.DELETE("/posts/:id", Delete)
    r.Run(":3001")
}
```

type.go

```
package main

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Book struct {
    gorm.Model
    Id           int    `gorm:"" json:"id"`
    BookName     string `gorm:"" json:"bookname"`
    Author       string `gorm:"" json:"authorname"`
    PagesNumber  int    `gorm:"" json:"pagesnumber"`
    Review       string `gorm:"" json:"bookreview"`
    BookImage    int    `gorm:"" json:"bookimage"`
    BookProgress int    `gorm:"" json:"bookProgress"`
    EndDate      string `gorm:"" json:"endDate"`
    StartDate    string `gorm:"" json:"startDate"`
}
```

api

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func AllBooks(g *gin.Context) {

    var books []Book

    db.Find(&books)
    g.JSON(200, books)
}

func OneBook(g *gin.Context) {
    id := g.Param("id")
    var book Book
    db.First(&book, id)
    if book.ID == 0 {
        g.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "data":  "Nothing",
            "error": "book not found",
        })
        return
    }
    g.JSON(http.StatusAccepted, gin.H{
        "data":  book,
        "error": "",
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be due to not setting the gorm tag correctly.

```golang
type Book struct {
    gorm.Model
    BookName     string `gorm:"column:book_name;comment:''" json:"book_name"`
    Author       string `gorm:"column:author;comment:''" json:"author"`
    PagesNumber  int    `gorm:"column:pages_number;comment:''" json:"pages_number"`
    Review       string `gorm:"column:review;comment:''" json:"review"`
    BookImage    int    `gorm:"column:book_image;comment:''" json:"book_image"`
    BookProgress int    `gorm:"column:book_progress;comment:''" json:"book_progress"`
    EndDate      string `gorm:"column:end_date;comment:''" json:"end_date"`
    StartDate    string `gorm:"column:start_date;comment:''" json:"start_date"`
}
```

And the fields of your database should be equal to the contents of the column.